# Why is my pygame game losing frames when displaying rects?

Tags: python, macos, pygame, frame-rate

Im trying to code a simple game, the game has a player object, and a floor using loops to create it. Im not sure why its losing frames soo quickly though. I have clock to tick 60 fps but quickly drops to 15 fps. Thanks in advance!

`main.py`

```
black = (0, 0, 0)
blue = (50, 60, 200)
white = (255, 255, 255)
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Platformer")

gravity = -0.5

player = Player(400, 0)

level1 = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]


]

    for y in range(0, len(level1)):
        for x in range(0, len(level1[y])):
            if level1[y][x] == 1:
                blockList.append(Block(x*32, y*32))

    window.fill(blue)

    for block in blockList:
        block.render(window)

    player.x += moveX

    player.update(gravity, blockList)
    player.render(window)

    clock.tick(60)
```

````
        for x in range(0, len(level1[y])):
            if level1[y][x] == 1:
                blockList.append(Block(x*32, y*32))``` Im pretty sure thats where the error is...
````

Comment: Are you doing this double-loop over `level1` every frame ?  Perhaps this can be moved to an initialisation section before entering the main loop.

Comment: how would i do that? Sorry im new to python

Comment: You will need to edit your question to include the entire code - or at least the main loop.  It's not possible to suggest changes without most of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good learning point in here.  One of the first steps in optimizing code is taking the unnecessary math out of the loops.  As suggested in comment, if you are running that double loop inside of each frame computation, it is probably slowing you down a lot.  Perhaps other things are too.

Let's assume that your "level 1" blocks are not changing frame-to-frame.  So, we can compute blacklist **before** you start your loop.

```
# make blocklist
level1= [[0,0, ... , 0],
              ...
         [1,1, ... , 1]]

blocklist = []
for y ...
  for x ...
    blocklist.append(...)

# now start your frame loop
while True:
  window.fill()
  for block in blocklist:
    ...
  clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: The double loop is an example of quadratic time.

Comment: sorry, super new to stackoverflow, dont even know how to properly format a question